# How do I resize software RAID partitions in GParted live?

Tags: linux, raid, gparted

I have a Linux RAID partition that I want to extend into empty space nondestructively. In GParted it has a lock symbol and right-clicking the partition brings up greyed out options. But on the GParted website it says it supports Linux software RAID. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Lock symbol means the partition is in active use. You need to mdadm -f and mdadm -r the device from the active array.

As far as I can see though, gparted-0.20.0 still isn't able to resize an inactive linux-raid partition.

EDIT This may be related to the version of md metadata you have going. [0.90 apparently stores metadata at the end of partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317035/how-to-grow-raid-1-following-disk-upgrade), so moving the end around isn't goint to just work(tm). I don't have a 1.x metadata array to test on, so not sure if gparted is able to resize that.

Comment: Just tried and failed to resize a RAID partition of a RAID 5 member, while it was in a USB dock, in a different machine than the array. Fails with gparted and with yast. Yast says "this partition type does not support resizing". I think it's safe to say that this does not work, and there's no way around failing, repartitioning and syncing each drive separately ...